# How can I detect, that my app is running on the Ripple Emulator?

Tags: cordova, emulation, hybrid, ripple

Is there a way to detect, that my application is currently running on the Ripple Emulator, instead of a real device? I want some workaround code to be ran only on the emulator.

Comment: I have created a small JS routine, based on a chozen reply:

 `function isOnRippleEmulator() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `userAgent` property in `navigator` object  and check for a ripple instance on your DOM with `window.parent.ripple`. Ripple-Emulator is a `browser` userAgent. Maybe you going to add firefoxOS. :)

#### Hint: This is not a direct case of ripple emulator. It allows to detect browser or mobile device in JavaScript.

```
//check if the application is running on a mobile device or desktop 
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/) 
    && !window.parent.ripple) {
    app.deviceType = 'mobile';
} else {
    app.deviceType = 'browser';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually works. I have created a routine based on this.

Comment: Doesn't work as my Ripple userAgent is: `"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.2; en-us; Nexus S Build/GRH78C) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1"`

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki thanks for the downvote so. It did work fine in the past but it seems like ripple has changed. I updated my answer so it should work for you.

Comment: I believe that checking window.parent.ripple is enough to know :)

Answer (score 8):

you can check if a ripple instance is aviable:
`if(typeof window.parent.ripple ==="undefined")`

if ripple is a object, ripple is running otherweise ripple is not running! 
Quick and easy.

**try to explain:**

The target app runs in an iframe. If a ripple session has started is an object named "ripple" instantiated (at this point it does not matter what makes the object "ripple"). It's enough just to know that the object has been created. Because with this knowledge, we know that the app runs in a ripple container.

With  `window.parent` we can query the parent node of a iframe, in this case, the ripple environment in which there is also the ripple object.